# I want to suppress deprecated API usage

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea

Environment: IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2022.2 Build 222.3345.118

I have overridden the method with @Deprecated annotation.
I want to suppress deprecated API usage on certain methods. But the Option+Enter action has only useless suggestions.

[image]

We tried to suppress it by means of SupressWornings and //noinspection ScalaDeprecation. I would like to disable Inspection as a last resort because there are some warnings that I want to suppress and others that I do not want to.

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`. If used in combination with others, use array literal syntax: `@SupressWarnings({ "serial", "deprecation" })`. Always try to use the smallest possible scope - variable / field before method / constructor before entire class.

Comment: I have tried that method, restarted and built the editor, but it still warns me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Scala you can use the [`@nowarn`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.2/scala/annotation/nowarn.html) annotation to this end. You can see a very nice rundown of how to use both this annotation locally or other options on the overall project [on this blog post by Lukas Rytz](https://www.scala-lang.org/2021/01/12/configuring-and-suppressing-warnings.html).

In your case, I believe you can use the following annotation:

```
@nowarn("cat=deprecation&origin=your\.package\.YourDeprecatedClass")
```

You can see an example of how I used this on [this commit](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/commit/0579ebdd770ab0f6a8cbbd45a09726dc79e9daa7).

As you can see, the annotation can be applied even to individual expression via type ascription, but you can also apply it to methods. In general, I like to keep my `@nowarn`s as specific and fine-scoped as possible. You can also tell the compiler to warn you when a `@nowarn` is not doing anything, so that you don't have to keep unused annotations around the code.

If you have deprecated APIs that you need to use (e.g. even though they are deprecated, you still need to test them) and the usages are all over the place, you might want to evaluate the option of configuring the warning suppression as a compiler option with something like

```
-Wconf:cat=deprecation&origin=your\.package\.YourDeprecatedClass
```

passed to the compiler. [Here](https://github.com/digital-asset/daml/commit/aec3390904ccc341648f4a9dc1761efb723d41b2#diff-c6df9dda4e353500adcf6736eeadbfd2d1053932e64675e96974bc69cf31e1b7R54) is an example of this as well (we use Bazel instead of SBT but I'm fairly sure that setting up SBT for this is quite simple).

For any other information, the blog post I linked above is an excellent source.